# The long exact sequence of compact manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology

If $M$ is a compact orientable manifold with boundary, is it necessary that in the long exact sequence ${H_n}(M,\partial M)\mathop  \to \limits^{{\partial _ * }} {H_{n - 1}}(\partial M)$,  ${{\partial _ * }}$ sends $1$ to $+1$ or $-1$ in ${H_{n - 1}}(\partial M)$ ?

Comment: Can you clear up the question? Is $M$ orientable? And how do you interpret what happens with an annulus?

Comment: @SteveD $M$ should be orientable and $1$ means fundamental class, I guess (the answer is "yes" than).

Comment: Yes, I thought as much, but the OP should state it more carefully.